# В плагине каруселе slick если нажать на картинку то происходит обводка. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

На картинке 5 можно увидеть обводку. Если нажать похожа на кнопку. Как убрать обводку?
[image: карусель]

Comment: Возможно у вас включен параметр focusOnSelect

Comment: Будь добр скачай и загляни. Потом напиши как это исправить.  https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/

Comment: Ок, в этой версии нету focusOnSelect, я решил проблему так: найди в index.html строку с css 
.slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
}
и запиши туда outline: none;

Comment: Спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я решил проблему так: найди в index.html строку с css .slick-slide { margin: 0px 20px; } и запиши туда outline: none;

Answer (score 0):

У вас картинка-ссылка? в файле со стилями пропишите img {border:0}

Comment: На картинке нет ссылки.

Comment: еще можно добавить outline: none;